# Google fonts stopped working suddenly. What caused this?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, google-webfonts

I am using [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) on my website at http://ryanscowles.com. They were working fine, up until a couple days ago. I didn't alter the fonts in the CSS, but they are no longer working. I was originally calling them with:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Enriqueta:700|Actor");
```

but for testing purposes, I am now trying to import them individually.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Enriqueta:400,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor);
```

Neither one seems to be loading, and in Chrome's web inspector the styles that apply the fonts seem to be crossed out. For example, the `h1` in the top left should be the Enriqueta font.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing quotes around the URLs.

Comment: url loads fine here. did you (or your IP range) get blacklisted for abuse or something? what happens if you manually hit that url in your browser?

Comment: @MarcB - All three of the URL's seem to load for me locally. I will check with my host to see if anything has been altered on their end.

Comment: @Oded - I added the quotes, but it still doesn't seem to do the trick. I had the quotes on the original, as well.

Comment: OK - thought that might be it, but there is nothing that needs quoting on those URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you have comments before the `@import` rules. The `@import` rule must come before all other content in the stylesheet and I believe this includes comments.

However I recommend against using `@import` for Google Web Fonts, try using the `link` method instead, such as:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Enriqueta:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This is a faster and more reliable method for adding stylesheets to your page, for more info see this article: [don't use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/).

Comment: This did the trick. It's strange to me that the `@import` was working correctly before, but seems to have stopped suddenly. Either way, it's working now! Thank you for the reply and the explanation.

Comment: came here for the same reason, `@import` doesn't work out of sudden and indeed there were comments before it. Now I use `link` method. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `//fonts.googleapis.com...` instead of `http://fonts.googleapis.com...` - helped for me.